# Is it possible to implement server push using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, server-push

Currently in my application I have a component which displays some information. Every minute it communicates using jetty with a server that contains csv file to see if it changed. I would like to improve this solution and have a possibility to update my component instantly when csv file changes.

I consider using Apache Camel because after receiving push about the change I want to send it also to another parts of the system e.g. using RMI.
I read the documentation of Apache Camel and I see that it is easy to receive, process and send data betweens components but I am not sure if it can also wait for notifications.
Maybe I should think about something other than camel?

Your help is so much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use MQTT and subsribe your clients to a server topic. There are other options too.

Comment: Camel has MQTT components which are so easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Camel is well equipped to deal with asynchronous calls such as those from a server push. Depending on how your server is going to send the updated csv file you can trigger the rest of your processes accordingly. For example, you can have an endpoint constantly listening for a file drop and whenever a new csv file shows up in a directory it will automatically trigger the rest of the processes. You can also do the same this with a webservice call or pulling the information from a queue somewhere.

UPDATE:

I ran out of characters in the comment below so I'll finish my thoughts here. With the server push method you won't be making an expensive web call to check if you file has changed. You will be implementing a listener that waits for a stimulus from the server. One of the methods I suggested was having the server push a file to you (using FTP or something) and you have a camel endpoint listen for it. By it's nature the camel endpoint is polling but this polling isn't expensive since you're just polling a local directory instead of making a web call. I don't know how much control you have over the server push but if you wanted to make the call truly asynchronous you can have the server push be in the form a webservice that will call a SOAP/REST endpoint that you expose. That webservice call would then trigger the rest of the routes/processes you want with zero polling.

Comment: My question is: how should I implement "an endpoint constantly listening for a file drop" with Apache Camel or another library?

Comment: @Peters_, that would be polling, which the [file component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) can do, but in your question you ask for a push solution.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a push solution, not polling. Actually it is not my server with the csv file. That is why I do not now when the update comes.

Comment: @Peters_, I think you have the terms push and pull/polling mixed up. If the process that produces the csv file is not under your control, and you cannot change it to push the file to you, i.e. call a server component of yours, then you need to poll for the file. The file and ftp components allow you to do that. Maybe others. If you want to use file you have to be able to mount the filesystem where the CSV file is placed. If you want to use FTP, then the other side has to offer you an FTP server.

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Yes the process that produces the csv is not under my control and I would like to have immediate update in my component when it occurs. When I poll I must do it cyclically and my update will not be immediate. Am I right?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how a server push works. Your old method was manually pinging the server every X period of time. This method is obviously expensive as you have to make a web call every time. Server push means that you have the server send you an unsolicited message when an update happens to your .csv file. This means that you won't be making calls to the server but you need to have some sort of listener on your client that know what to do when the server sends you an update. I'm running out of characters in this comment so I'll update the answer post above.